# como fazer multiplos eventos em um único botão tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa noite, estou tentando criar dois eventos com um botão no tkinter, no caso o botão iria descriptografar arquivos e aparecer uma imagem de cadeado aberto entretanto como estou iniciando na programação estou com muita dificuldade de fazer isso, quando crio apenas o codigo de descriptografar e imprimir a mensagem funciona perfeitamente mas quando tento incluir a imagem do cadeado aberto não funciona.

def DECRYPT_FILE():

```
    def decrypt(filename):
        key = entry1.get()
        f = Fernet(key)
        with open(filename, "rb") as file:
            encrypted_data = file.read()
        decrypted_data = f.decrypt(encrypted_data)
        with open(filename, "wb") as file:
            file.write(decrypted_data)


    with open('logs/path.txt') as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        while line:
            filename = line.strip()
            try:
                decrypt(filename)
            except PermissionError:
                print("!Permission denied")
            line = fp.readline()
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='SEUS ARQUIVOS FORAM DESCRIPTOGRAFADOS') # Titulo
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', int(height/50)))
    label1.config(background='black', foreground='red')
    canvas1.create_window(int(width/2), int(height/7)*50, window=label1)
    OPEN = PhotoImage(file="open.png")
    lb = Label(root, image=imagem)
    lb.config(background='black', foreground='black')
    lb.place(x = 560, y = 523)
    fp.close()
    shutil.rmtree(PATH+'/logs', ignore_errors=True)

    canvas1.create_window(int(width/2), 650, window=label1)  

button1 = tk.Button(text='Decrypt', command=DECRYPT_FILE)
button1.config(background='red')
canvas1.create_window(int(width/2), int(height/17)*13, window=button1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi parte do problema usando uma função genérica para combinar funções:

def combine_funcs(*func):  #combina argumentos
def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
for f in func:
f(*args, **kwargs)
return combined_func

```
def func1():  #argumento de cadeado aberto
    imagem = PhotoImage(file="open.png")
    lb=Label(root, image=imagem)
    lb.config(background='black', foreground='black')
    lb.place(x = 560, y = 523)

def func2():  #argumento de descriptografia
```

Porém agora onde é para surgir a imagem fica preto...